# Oscilloscope or bench multi-meter for ultra high sensor sample rate measurement

Tags: sensor, oscilloscope, multimeter, load-cell

I need a device to measure the output of a load cell at very high sample rates. I am aiming for a sample rate of at least 100 kHz. For this goal, I wanted to ask if it would be better to use a bench multi-meter measuring resistance, or an oscilloscope and a 5v dc power supply. If I were to use an oscilloscope, how would I set the trigger to allow me to capture the very short change in voltage? Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Comment: What are you actually trying to measure?

Comment: ”_how would I set the trigger to allow me to capture the very short change in voltage?”_ With the normal edge trigger set to a suitable level? Perhaps with AC coupling.

Comment: Impact force of a gunshot

Comment: O'scopes tend to have very low resolution, typically 8 bits. Bench multimeters tend to be very slow. You can get reasonably priced 12 bit digitisation at 100 kHz in a datalogger or signal digitiser. You play with the triggering once you have the setup working.

Comment: 100kHz is certainly not "ultra high rate". You should clarify how many samples you need to acquire at this rate for each gunshot.

Comment: What resolution do you need? 100kHz is *very* slow for an oscilloscope but most oscilloscopes are also only 8-bit. You might need a DAQ if you're looking for something like 100kHz @ 16-bits.

Comment: a mechanical solution may be more suitable ... ask at https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you're going to be blowing up load cells you can probably afford a nice 16 or 24 bit NI PCIe DAQ card. 100 KHz sounds pretty low for a gunshot though, I'd think you'd be at least MHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sampling rate is not a problem for oscilloscopes, but most lower cost oscilloscopes (e.g. less than about $2k) are only 8-bit resolution. Very expensive ones (over $5k) can be 10-bit resolution.

Some well-known brand bench multimeters can sample at 50 kHz, and store 1M samples; These will have plenty of resolution (16-24 bits) these have a USB interface and are easy to use to manually capture those samples; triggering may however be an issue.

If you can use 10-12 bits resolution, a small Arduino-based device (e.g. PJRC's Teensy 4.0) can easily sample reliably at 1 MHz. You'd have to write some software to customize it for your specific case, including triggering.

Comment: LeCroy has a bunch of oscilloscopes that are 12-bit. They'd mostly be in your "Very expensive" category, though for professional work $5k is more on the cheap side in terms of price; the very expensive ones cost over $100k.

Comment: On the cheaper end of thing, Rigol has some low-end oscilloscopes that claim to be 12-bit, though I'm not sure how they measure up to the LeCroy ones that cost ten times as much.

Comment: This was very helpful. I am repetitively new to EE, and I was unaware that common ADCs could sample so fast. I ended up going with the MCP33131 ADC connected to a raspberry pi through the SPI interface, mounted on the following board: https://widgetlords.com/products/pi-spi-8ai-16b-raspberry-pi-analog-input-16-bit-4-20-ma-interface?variant=30311136690260 Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

both device classes arent really up to the job you describe based on your tentative information.

Bench DMMs can have internal sample rates of up to 100 kHz, but are not designed to stream all of these samples out. You might get a bunch/burst but not all without interuption.

Oscilloscopes have very bad resolution at extremely high speed of GS/s. And again are not designed to stream these samples out.

What you want typically is referred to as data logger or data acquisition system. You will find many options when you search that. 100kHz is on the slow side, you can get ADCs with up to 24 bit at such sampling rates.